# How to get value from StepExecutionContext

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch JdbcCursorItemReader. It is defined as @JobScope. See method signature below.

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<MasterList> queryStagingDbReader(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['" + JobParamConstants.PARAM_FROM_DATE + "']}") Date jobFromDate,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['" + JobParamConstants.PARAM_TO_DATE + "']}") Date jobToDate) {
```

This JdbcCursorItemReader is part of step 2 in my job.

In step 1 of my job I have only a tasklet. Inside this tasklet I am building a list of dates which I would like my JdbcCursorItemReader in step 2 to know about.

My initial thought was to add my list of dates to the stepExecutionContext in my tasklet like so.

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public Tasklet createJobDatesTasklet(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['" + JobParamConstants.PARAM_FROM_DATE + "']}") Date jobFromDate,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['" + JobParamConstants.PARAM_TO_DATE + "']}") Date jobToDate) {

    return new Tasklet() {

        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
            LocalDate start = jobFromDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
            LocalDate end = jobToDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

            List<LocalDate> jobDates = new ArrayList<>();
            while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
                jobDates.add(start);
                start = start.plusDays(1);
            }
            //ADDING TO CONTEXT HERE
            chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getExecutionContext().put("jobDates", jobDates);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
    };
}
```

And then to grab the list of dates from my JdbcCursorItemReader. But when I try to grab the step execution context inside my JdbcCursorItemReader it tells me that it cannot wire it in. And I think that is because my bean is @JobScope.

What can I do to grab my list of dates from the StepExecutionContext or alternatively can I do anything else to make this work for me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write it to the step context, rather write it to the Job Context, so that all the steps of the Job have the access to the data as below.

```
 StepContext stepContext         = chunkContext.getStepContext();
 StepExecution stepExecution     = stepContext.getStepExecution();
 JobExecution jobExecution         = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
 ExecutionContext jobContext     = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();

jobContext.put("jobDates", jobDates);
```

The below blog speaks about it

http://techie-mixture.blogspot.com/2016/07/passing-values-between-spring-batch.html